range function not working for performing subtraction
I have create a list variable (Balance) using range function
My requirement is to subtract expenses from earnings and place the output in balance variable.
earnings = [10, 20, 30, 24, 18]
expenses = [8, 14, 15, 20, 10]
balance = list(range(1, 6))

for i in balance:
   balance[i] = earnings[i] - expenses[i]    

Output:
IndexError 
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [96], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for i in balance:
----> 2     balance[i] = earnings[i] - expenses[i]

IndexError: list index out of range

Expected Result:
Subtract expenses from earnings and place the output in balance variable.

Try adding a print(balance) as the first action inside your loop to see why.

@JonSG that is not the issue here

indices in expenses are from 0 to 4 while balance is from 1 to 5, expenses[5] will give IndexError: list index out of range.

balance will be defined as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], and the indices of a list in Python go from [0...len(list)-1]. So, when you iterate over the balance list, 5 > len(expenses) - 1, and you get an IndexError.

I agree that the main issue is that python lists are 0 indexed, and that index 5 is thus out of bounds.

Two problems in your example: First, there is no definition of earnings-list, second you iterate over the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 but you have only the following indices in the expenses list: 0,1,2,3,4 so for your numbers 5 from the range there appears an IndexError

Just to give another solution, for others, do not answer the question here: balance = [a-b for a,b in zip(earnings, expenses)]

This question is similar to: Subtracting 2 lists in Python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Python lists use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering
A couple of ways to write this:
earnings = [10, 20, 30, 24, 18]
expenses = [8, 14, 15, 20, 10]

balance = []
for i in range(len(expenses)):
   balance.append(earnings[i] - expenses[i])

earnings = [10, 20, 30, 24, 18]
expenses = [8, 14, 15, 20, 10]

balance = []
for earning, expense in zip(earnings, expenses):
   balance.append(earning - expense)

earnings = [10, 20, 30, 24, 18]
expenses = [8, 14, 15, 20, 10]

balance = [
    earning - expense
    for earning, expense in zip(earnings, expenses)
]

(I would favour the last one, just looking at this particular bit of code in isolation)
